# 7zip standalone command line to split a large file

Tags: 7zip

I am using 7zip standalone command line(7za.exe) to split a large file and also using 7zip application(7zFM.exe)

when I am using 7zFM.exe to split a file that is 6GB in size with the following parameters

```
a)Archive format :7z
b)compression - level = 1-Fastest
c)compression method = LZMA2
d)Dictionary size = 256KB
e)Word size = 32
f)Solid block size = 32MB
g)Number of CPU threads = 4/4
h)Memory usage compression = 80%
i)Split by volume = 20M
```

it takes **5 minutes** to make the splits.
BUT if I use the standalone command line to perform the same operation for the same file using the following

`"C:\7z2201-extra\7za.exe" a -v20m -mx=1 -mmt=off "output_path\abc.7z" "input_path\xyz"`

(The -mx=1 and -mmt=off parameters are used to reduce the  process time from 25 minutes to 15 minutes)
this process takes about **15 minutes**

My problem: I want to split the file in the same amount i.e. 5 minutes using 7zip standalone command line

(configuration of the system that is used is it has windows 10 OS )

Note: I don't want use the 7zFM.exe via command line.

Answer (score 1):

The 7zFM.exe is faster than 7za.exe because 7zip application prioritizes the GUI over the standalone. To get the 7zip standalone to work as similar as possible to the GUI is the best solution and to achieve that we need to try to convert all the parameters or as much as parameters possible to command line mode so the following parameters will be converted as

```
a)Archive format :7z
b)compression - level = 1-Fastest
c)compression method = LZMA2
d)Dictionary size = 256KB
e)Word size = 32
f)Solid block size = 32MB
g)Number of CPU threads = 4/4
h)Memory usage compression = 80%
i)Split by volume = 20M
```

The converted standalone will be as

```
"C:\7z2201-extra\7za.exe" a -t7z -mx=1 -m0=LZMA2 -md=256k -mfb=32 -ms=32m -mmt=4 -v20m "output_path\abc.7z" "input_path\xyz.txt"
```

The GUI and command line almost take the same time to produce the splits.